# How to correctly set background image in a HTML page using a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change my background image when my mouse move over a image and here i have attached a sample scenario here my question is how i set my background image width and hight as cover inside my function! OR do i need to set some css attributes.or what is the easiest way?

```js
function change(state) {
  var lampImg = document.getElementById("lamp");
  lampImg.src = "lamp_" + state + ".png";
  var statusDiv = document.getElementById("statusDiv");
  statusDiv.innerHTML = "The lamp is " + state;
  if (state == "on") {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.body.background = "back.jpg";
    statusDiv.style.color = "black";
    statusDiv.innerHTML = "The lamp is " + state;
  }
  if (state == "off") {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
    statusDiv.style.color = "white";
    document.body.background = null;
    statusDiv.innerHTML = "The lamp is " + state;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body bgcolor="gray">

  <div style="float:left;width:50%">
    <div>
      <img width="200px" height="300px" id="lamp" src="lamp_off.png" />
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="statusDiv">put mouse over the switch!</div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;width:50%;">
    <div style="float:left;">
      <img width="40px" height="60px" src="test_on.png" onmouseover="change('on')" onmouseout="change('off')" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>









</body>

</html>
```

` to do that

Comment: Use CSS classes. Add a class and remove a class.

Comment: you can do it with jquery and it takes only 1,2 rows code http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Use CSS to set the cover, use javascript to change the image. The css should stay the same. Also `widtdocument.body.style.background.size = "cover";h="40px" ` isn't a valid attribute for the img tag *Or any tag*

Comment: You are looking for `document.body.style.backgroundSize = 'cover'`, but you also need the prefixes for older browser, so that would be  `document.body.style.[PREFIX]BackgroundSize = 'cover'` with prefix being `webkit`, `moz` and `ms`. In CSS, values contain a `-` in the middle. in JS they're CamelCased.

Comment: @NewToJS i corrected it! it happened when i copy the code into code snippet sorry!

Comment: @somethinghere yeah thanks! i'll look into that definitely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to set the backgroundSize property as such:

```
document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
```

And keep in mind prefixes, as this would mean many more lines:

```
document.body.style.webkitBackgroundSize = "cover";
document.body.style.mozBackgroundSize = "cover";
document.body.style.msBackgroundSize = "cover";
document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
```

The best way is to use a class, but since you are using vanilla JS it's harder to consistently remove or add classes for this. An example would be:

#### CSS

```
.cover { background-size: cover; }
```

#### JS

```
document.body.className = "cover";
```

If you use the former method, however, heres a rule of thumb: whatever has `-` in the style attribute should be `camelCased` (actually that a `dromedaryCase` as it does not begin with a capital letter). So `background-image` becomes `backgroundImage` etc...

Answer (score 0):

I did it with the sample code and it was a simple error but learned a lot and thanks for all your help!

```js
function change(state) 
{
   var lampImg = document.getElementById("lamp");
   lampImg.src = "lamp_" + state + ".png";
   var statusDiv = document.getElementById("statusDiv");
   statusDiv.innerHTML = "The lamp is " + state;

   if(state=="on")
   {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="white";
    document.body.background="back.jpg";
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
    statusDiv.style.color="black";
    statusDiv.innerHTML = "The lamp is " + state;
   }

   if(state=="off")
   {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="gray";
    statusDiv.style.color="white";
    document.body.background=null;
    statusDiv.innerHTML = "The lamp is " + state; 
   }
}
```

```html
<html>
<title>My lampstatus</title>
<head>
<body bgcolor="gray">

<div style="float:left;width:50%">
<div > 
 <img width="200px" height="300px" id="lamp" src="lamp_off.png"/>
</div><br/>
<div id="statusDiv"> put mouse over the switch!</div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:50%;">
 <div style="float:left;">
  <img width="40px" height="60px" src="test_on.png" onmouseover="change('on')" onmouseout="change('off')" />
 </div>
</div><br/>

  </body>
  </html>
```

and I know I need to add these compatible codes to each browsers I'll look into that with my code! And yeah jQuery will be a concern!